# How to loop through json data php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to loop through JSON data in php.

```
array:2 [
  "cart" => array:3 [
    0 => array:4 [
      "id" => 3
      "name" => "ying"
      "price" => "4000"
    ]
    1 => array:4 [
      "id" => 2
      "name" => "yang"
      "price" => "4000"
    ]
    2 => array:4 [
      "id" => 4
      "name" => "foo"
      "price" => "5000"
    ]
  ]
  "total" => 13000
]
```

I've used the json_decode function and a foreach over the data.

```
foreach (json_decode($arr) as $item) {
    $item['name'];
}
```

I want to be able to get each "cart" item and the single "total" data but I keep getting an illegal offset error when i try to call things like $item['name']

Comment: It's an array within an array. You are not accounting for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) doc:

> **Note:** When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

If you dont pass 2nd argument as true then it will be treated as object as below.

```
$arr = json_decode($arr);
$names = [];
foreach ($arr->cart as $item) {
    $names[] = $item->name;
}
echo $arr->total;// this is how you will get total.
```

If you pass 2nd argument as true then it will be treated as associative array as below.

```
$names  = [];
$arr = json_decode($arr, true);
foreach ($arr['cart'] as $item) {
    $names[] = $item['name'];
}
echo $arr['total'];// this is how you will get total.
```

In your code, your data is having two main keys viz. `cart` and `total`. From which, you are trying to fetch the data of `cart` which I specified in my answer.

Comment: This works but it returns data from the first array only and i can't access 'total'

Comment: You should point out that the data need is in the `cart` array and not the root of the decoded array. Your answer is correct but just lacks a complete explanation.

Comment: Right John, i need to be able to get 'cart' data and total.

Comment: I made changes in my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks Rahul but i'm trying to fetch data for 'cart' and 'total'

Comment: `$arr->total` if true not passed and `$arr['total']` if true passed. Once check my edit portion

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks Rahul.